# 2 Volume RAID 10 on a single RAID controller

Tags: sas, raid10, workstation

Motherboards Supermicro X10DRH-CT
Onboard Raid Broadcom Mega Raid SLI 3108,
Motherboard has 2 mini SAS port for an other 4 SAS Drives.

Question, Can I create Second Raid 10 Volume without interfering with the first one?

Comment: add them and test, Update the bios/Firmware infront of ususally you are not blocked by because its a common scenario

Comment: It’s for personal lab, so would be great to know before buying disks.

Comment: https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/motherboard/X10DRH-CT as ususally it is possible, because i ran an similar setup on a consumer board